# Optimisation of route finding code

Tags: c#, linq, iteration

Small bit of background first. I am developing a system that generates a "route" between locations. Locations have a pre-defined list of neighbours not limited to those adjacent to it. The search can safely assume that by picking the closest neighbour (numerically) to the target destination, it is making the optimal move towards it.

I have working code as shown below:

```
public Route GetRoute(int StartPoint, int Destination)
{
    Route returnRoute = new Route();
    returnRoute.steps = new List<int>();
    bool locationReached = false;
    int selectedNeighbour;
    int distanceFromTarget;
    int currentPoint = StartPoint; // set the current point to the start point

    while (!locationReached)
    {
        selectedNeighbour = 0;
        distanceFromTarget = 5000; // nominal amount guaranteed to be overwritten

        var neighbours = locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LocationID == currentPoint).Neighbours;

        for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.Length; i++)
        {
            // get the current neighbours, then check proximity
            int currentNeighbour = neighbours[i];
            int tempDistance = Math.Abs( currentNeighbour - Destination );

            // if nearer than previous neighbour, set it as the chosen location
            if ( tempDistance < distanceFromTarget )
            {
                distanceFromTarget = tempDistance;
                selectedNeighbour = currentNeighbour;

                // if the selected neighbour is the destination, we're done
                if ( selectedNeighbour == Destination )
                    locationReached = true;
            }

        } // for

        // add the selected neighbour if we found one
        if ( selectedNeighbour != 0 )
        {
            currentPoint = selectedNeighbour;
            returnRoute.steps.Add(selectedNeighbour);
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log ("No Route Found");
            return returnRoute; 
        }

    } // while

    return returnRoute;
}
```

My question is regarding the loop of the neighbours (int[]) variable. How can this best be optimised? I've seen some use of linq and ordering, but also comments that this approach might be inefficient. I need efficiency over neatness here.

Many thanks.

Comment: Utilizing LINQ in lieu of basic loops is pretty much always about emphasizing code clarity. If your code works, then there seems like little reason to switch to LINQ.

Comment: If you want any kind of optimization try looking into Dijkstra's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm